# Get the CN out of certificates information

Tags: filter, ansible, data-manipulation

I am trying to do a nice print out of the data from Ansible but have no idea on how to manipulate it.
This is what I have in the `debug` — I am trying to somehow manipulate the data so that it only gives me a `CN=` (without the `CN=`) value, and not the whole subject string:

```json
[
        {
            "certkey": "Verisign_ca3_cer",
            "daystoexpiration": 0,
            "status": "Expired",
            "subject": " C=US,O=VeriSign, Inc.,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06,CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA"
        },
        {
            "certkey": "Verisign_ca5_cer",
            "daystoexpiration": 0,
            "status": "Expired",
            "subject": " C=US,O=VeriSign, Inc.,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10,CN=VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3"
        }
]
```

I wanted output similar to this:

```json
[
        {
            "certkey": "Verisign_ca3_cer",
            "daystoexpiration": 0,
            "status": "Expired",
            "subject": "CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA"
        },
        {
            "certkey": "Verisign_ca5_cer",
            "daystoexpiration": 0,
            "status": "Expired",
            "subject": "CN=VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**Select 'CN' from 'subject'.**"*

A: Let's assume your data is a list of dictionaries, e.g.

```yaml
    certs:
      - {"certkey": "Verisign_ca3_cer",
         "daystoexpiration": 0,
         "status": "Expired",
         "subject": " C=US,O=VeriSign, ...
```

Create the list of the parsed subjects, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        subjs: "{{ subjs|d([]) + [_subj] }}"
      loop: "{{ certs|map(attribute='subject')|list }}"
      vars:
        _subj: "{{ dict(item.split(',')|
                        select('match', '.*=.*')|
                        map('trim')|
                        map('split', '=')|
                        list) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  subjs:
  - C: US
    CN: VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
    O: VeriSign
    OU: Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06
  - C: US
    CN: VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3
    O: VeriSign
    OU: Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10
```

and select the attribute 'CN'

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        CN: "{{ subjs|map(attribute='CN')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  CN:
  - VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
  - VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3
```

---

Combine the certificates with the updated attribute *subject*, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        cert_cn: "{{ cert_cn|d([]) + 
                     [item.0|combine({'subject': 'CN=' ~ item.1.CN})] }}"
      loop: "{{ certs|zip(subjs) }}"
```

gives the output you want

```yaml
  cert_cn:
  - certkey: Verisign_ca3_cer
    daystoexpiration: 0
    status: Expired
    subject: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
  - certkey: Verisign_ca5_cer
    daystoexpiration: 0
    status: Expired
    subject: CN=VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3
```

Comment: Thank you! What I really wanted is to have the data as is, but only have the CN part of the subject, together with other cert info

Comment: I see. What is preventing you from putting it into the question? [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Don't forget to put an example of what you really want.

Comment: A really marvellous answer. I am also wondering why it did not match the question.

Comment: It's only a personal view =) I have worked on it for half a day and it just makes sense to me, but you are reading it differently to what was meant.

Comment: @Sergey Fox, see the updated answer. See also [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and "What are comments for, and when shouldn't I comment?" in particular. Delete your comments here. They don't provide clarification, constructive criticism, or minor information. Focus on your question instead. SO is a Q&A site hence the Q&A must be reusable. [Nobody is interested in personal views](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I just went the regex_replace way

```
msg: '{{ result.json.sslcertkey | regex_replace(" C=.*?CN=", "")   }}'
```